# Задача Мороженое

Tags: python

> В кафе мороженое продают по три шарика и по пять шариков. Можно ли купить ровно `k` шариков мороженого?

Хотелось бы узнать решение с использованием только условного оператора, без циклов.

```
k = int(input())

if k % 5 == 3 or k % 5 == 0 or k % 3 == 0 or k % 3 == 2:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: А мне хотелось, чтобы Вы своим домашним заданием занялись сами, но это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: Хммм, интересно. Такое дело, это не домашнее задание, а просто задача из интернета. Я пытался ее решить, но получил "Неполное решение" и никак не могу разобраться почему. Сюда я написал с надеждой узнать как же она решается. В интернете все решения через циклы, но эта задача в теме Условный Оператор, который стоит перед циклами, соответственно решается она и без циклов. Надеюсь, что stackoverflow все-таки поможет мне с этим разобраться.

Comment: Добавьте свой код в текст вопроса.

Comment: Ну 3,5,6 или больше 8 проверить не так и сложно) а у вас не то, у вас и 2 можно, и кучу всего нельзя.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://ideone.com/gSY6ii

```
n = int(input())
print("NO" if n < 3 or n == 4 or n == 7 else "YES")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k = int(input())
if k % 3 == 0 or k % 5 == 0 or k % 3 == 2 or k % 5 == 3:
    print('YES')
elif k >= 6 and (k - 6) % 5 == 0:
    print('YES')
elif k >= 9 and (k - 9) % 5 == 0:
    print('YES')
elif k >= 12 and (k - 12) % 5 == 0:
    print('YES')
elif k <= 4:
    print('NO')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: `if k % 3 == 0 or k % 5 == 0 or k % 3 == 2 or k % 5 == 3:` — для `k = 2` вы получите **YES**, а это неправильно.